# How to stop android auto overwriting debug apk overnight?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a device that I use to test on in the office, I manually install the debug variant of the app on the device.

However when I leave the office and come back overnnight I see that the app has been overwritten by the production version.

How can I stop this behavior so that I keep the debug variant from being overwritten?

Comment: That is strange

Comment: probably android thinks that you installed hacked version  of the app and replaces it with "good" and verified version from play market.  Did you try to bump app version so it would be higher than the version at play market? -

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny hmm that's a good idea I'll try give it a shot